# Why "media seems to be more than allowed space and cannot be uploaded" and how to get fast uploading of images to social sites such as Twitter?

Tags: camera, twitter

I have photo-uploading such as Twitter in my default Android -camera-app. It works some time but some time it fails, problems such as lag and odd errors about the size of the pictures. I don't like it. I want a fast uploading because I like to use Twitter uploading in not-so-important -situation such as draft-uploading and so on -- situations that usually do not last that long. It should not be hard, just a `$ mogrify -resize LIMIT` -command in sending but has someone done this app or is this just a bug?

**Helper questions**

> 1. How can I fix this lag problem?
> 2. How can I fix the reliability problem?
> 3. How can I fast upload photos to social sites such as Twitter?
> 4. Does there exist better apps to make the images just right size for uploading images?

Comment: Why don't you just turn the resolution of your camera down, then your images will be smaller.

Comment: @cjk how do you do it and what is the limit? And what is causing the lagging? I see your idea of turning resolution down as a way not solving the main problem i.e. finding better social image sharing -app.

Comment: It depends on your phone and the camera software, but somewhere within it should be a setting for how many megapixels you are using.

Comment: There are lots of Twitter apps that include photo support. Ditto camera apps. Without knowing what phone you have, we can't give any more specific advice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are lots of apps like

1. [Image Shrink Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.anolivetree.imageshrinklite)
2. [Resize Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.nsystem.resize_lite)
3. [Share Image](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.pecom.sendimage)
4. and many others, just search the market

Instead of sharing to Twitter, just share to these apps, choose from a list of predefined sizes, and reshare to Twitter. You can do this from any apps that can share images to any apps that can receive shared images.

Comment: ...which one would you recommend and why? I want just Twitter and fast usage. I want that the resizing is an automatic action, I don't want to waste time to decide some percentages to upload things such as school notes to Twitter.

Comment: @hhh: it's a bug in your Twitter client for not ensuring that the image fits Twitter's image requirement. I don't know which client you're using as there are many of them, but the proper fix to this is to contact your Twitter client's developer and have them fix that. You'd be hard pressed to find anyone writing an app that specifically address this bug for your specific Twitter client. In the mean time, these apps can do the resizing for you. it's not a bug in Camera app because Camera are not aware (and should not be aware) of Twitter's image requirement.

Comment: @hhh: as for which I recommend, I think Image Shrink Lite is the fastest and easiest. It's also the most limited in its options though, the other apps provides more options if you needed it.